# Getting decendant node that contains ":"?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have loaded a XML into a XDocument that looks something like this :

```
<MyXML xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Client.Main.GUI.Report">
  <Wrapper xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Business.Entity">
    <d2p1:_MultipelAttributId>156</d2p1:_MultipelAttributId>
  </Wrapper>
</MyXML>
```

Now I need to get the value of _MultipelAttributId but when stating this :

```
XElement element = (from cml2 in doc.Descendants("d2p1:_MultipelAttributId") select cml2).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get exception about the ":"?

So how do I get the valiue?

Comment: use `XNamespace`. It must be declared somewhere within your xml.

Comment: The XML is not possible to change, but I have updated it to match the real XML better. All I need is to get the _MultipelAttributId

Comment: This XML is invalid, as you are using the namespace prefix `d2p1` but without declaring it.

Comment: I added some more to the XML, is it correct now?

Comment: Yes it is correct now. [L.B's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12797857/588868) rely on this namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element name you're querying is not correct. Try this:

```
XElement element = (
    from cml2 in doc.Descendants()
    where cml2.Name.LocalName == "_MultipelAttributId"
    select cml2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think the solution that uses namespacing is better. Your solution does not prevent element naming collisions, while namespaces can remove any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Business.Entity"; 

var element = xDoc.Descendants(ns + "_MultipelAttributId").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article explains well how to work with namespaces in Linq to XML
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669152.aspx

```
XNamespace d2p1 = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApp.Business.Entity";
XElement multipelAttributId = doc.Descendants(d2p1 + "_MultipelAttributId").FirstOrDefault();
```

Notice that you can seamly create an XNamespace or an XName from a string because Microsoft have writen inplicit casts for these types.